# Add different watermarks to same pdf file

Tags: pdf, watermark

I have a multi-page PDF file (exported from an excel sheet).
Now I need to add about 60 different names as watermarks to every page of this PDF.

In the end I need a seperate file for each name with the corresponding watermark. So for example Name A as a watermark on the PDF saved as NameA.pdf, Name B as NameB.pdf and so on.

I find a lot of tools that allow me to add one watermark to multiple PDF files, but not the other way round.

Because I need to do this multiple times every year it would be possible to generate an image or stamp PDF for each name for future use. But I somehow need to automate the watermarking. It's driving me crazy how much time gets wasted doing it manually.

Comment: You may want to specify the OS you are using.  In linux  scripting tjis should not be that hard.

Answer (score 0):

DTP software like Scribus or inDesign support data merge, so you can place the PDF sheets as pages in the DTP software, and then use data merge functionality to get the names in.

You can also just try a multi-page Word merge with PDF pages as watermarks or set "behind text." One minor problem I have had with this is that Word files seem to baloon in size more than doing this via PDF.

Alternatively, you can do a "mail merge" in e.g. Word of just the names placed appropriately on blank sheets, and then add the PDF as a watermark to these unique sheets ("add one watermark to many").

This is obviously complicated by the multi-page nature of the PDF, but one could split the PDF into individual pages, do the above, and then compile them by name back into multi-page

Comment: Thank you so much.
InDesign sadly didn't do what I wanted. You can do the data merge, but it saves everything as one document. I'd have to seperate each individual document by hand.

The hint regarding Word helped me alot, though I'd have to test it with the real document at work.
I found the macro formletter2pdf that allowed me to use a WordArt with a letter field linked to an excel sheet to print individual pdf files with the serial letter function in Word. That's almost exactly what I looked for. Though I have to see how it works with the actual document I need this for.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be automated using shell scripting together with a PDF manipulation like [HexaPDF](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/documentation/reference/hexapdf.1.html#watermark) or [qpdf](https://qpdf.sourceforge.io/).

You said that you can pre-generate the watermark PDFs with the names beforehand. Once they are generated you loop through the watermark PDFs and apply each to the multi-page PDF.

Here is an example:

```bsh
$ for I in names/*.pdf; do hexapdf watermark -w "$I" -t stamp multi-page.pdf "multi-$I"; done
```

This will

- use `names/*.pdf` as the watermark PDF, i.e. the single-page PDFs with the names,
- use `multi-page.pdf` as the target PDF containing multiple pages,
- and will generate files with the prefix `multi-` for each watermark PDF.

The command line is for Linux or macOS but can easily be adopted to Windows.